# WPF/XAML: Viewing/editing XML file in a TextBox

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml

I'm rather new to WPF so please bear with me. I'm trying to bind an XML file to a TextBox so I can view the content and edit the file. I tried several suggestions already (SO, Google, ...) but I can't seem to get this working.

My XMLDataProvider looks like this:

```
<Window.Resources>

    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="test" Source="U:\x\2616004.xml" />

</Window.Resources>
```

My TextBox is within a TabItem and looks like this:

```
  <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
       <TextBox x:Name="tbBiblio" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="548" Margin="7,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="773" 
                                 Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource test}, XPath=/*/}" />
  </Grid>
```

If I run the application it just gives me an empty TextBox. I also tried different XML files, TextBlock instead of a TextBox and so on.

Suggestions and help are much appreciated. 
Thanks!

**Edit:**

With Philip Campbell's suggestion the content of the XML file is now correctly parsed into the TextBox. How do I get the TextBox now to show the "raw" file with its tags?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the Output Window when you debug your program?

Comment: Sorry, the original code includes a "<", I just missed it in the post. I don't get any errors so far while debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43933107/wpf-xaml-viewing-editing-xml-file-in-a-textbox/43933509#comment74898680_43933107) suggests, if you look at the output window you'll see what the error is:

```
XML binding failed. Cannot obtain result node collection because of bad source node or bad Path...
```

Which means that your XPath is invalid. I don't know what format your XML is in, or what elements you're trying to read, but changing the XPath to "*" should give you a good starting point, ie:

```
{Binding Source={StaticResource test}, XPath=*}
```

Comment: Oh yeah, it never came to my mind to actually take a look at the output window and you both were right. It was that error. The change to XPath=* helped! It shows the parsed content now. But how do I get the TextBox to show the raw file with all the Tags?